# Unable to unpack tor-browser git repo

Tags: manjaro, tor

I was going to install tor-browser. I had download package from [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/). I had cloned a git repo

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/tor-browser.git
```

Then, I was trying to unpack it.

```
cd tor-browser
makepkg -s
```

I was getting error/output something just like this :

```
Validating source files with sha256sums...
    tor-browser.desktop.in ... Passed
    tor-browser.in ... Passed
    tor-browser.png ... Passed
    tor-browser.svg ... Passed
==> Validating source_x86_64 files with sha256sums...
    tor-browser-linux64-10.0.16_en-US.tar.xz ... Passed
    tor-browser-linux64-10.0.16_en-US.tar.xz.asc ... Skipped
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
    tor-browser-linux64-10.0.16_en-US.tar.xz ... FAILED (unknown public key EB774491D9FF06E2)
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the instructions.  The very first (pinned) comment on the [Package Details: tor-browser](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tor-browser/) page says:

> Before running makepkg, you must do this (as normal user):
>
> ```
> $ gpg --auto-key-locate nodefault,wkd --locate-keys torbrowser@torproject.org
> ```

The build is failing because the public key which signed the package is unknown.  The command above installs that key into your gpg keyring.

Comment: I got a message `sub   rsa4096 2018-05-26 [S] [expires: 2021-06-12]`. So, the package will expire in 2021-06-12.. Do I have to run and unpack tor-browser again at that time?

Comment: That means the **key** will expire on 2021-06-12, not the package.   You'll probably need to install an updated key if you want to re-compile or compile a newer version after that date.   The gpg key is only used to verify that the source code you downloaded hasn't been tampered with, before you compile it.   If you're not planning to re-compile, the existing tor browser binary will keep working.

Comment: I got [an error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650587/error-while-installing-tor-browser) while trying to install/unpack it.