# error while installing tor-browser

Tags: manjaro, tor

I was following the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prQOXvRQiqo) to install tor-browser. I was installing/unpacking the [git repo](https://aur.archlinux.org/tor-browser.git). I had successfully executed following command

```
makepkg -s
```

When I executed

```
sudo pacman -U tor-browser-linux64-10.0.16_en-US.tar.xz
```

Then, I got some error. That tutorial said if I face any error than I should install `base-devel`. I had installed that. Then, I tried to execute above command again. But, when it was executing for low battery error my laptop had turned off. So, I had started my laptop again. And, executed same command again. I got following error then.

```
loading packages...
error: missing package metadata in tor-browser-linux64-10.0.16_en-US.tar.xz
error: 'tor-browser-linux64-10.0.16_en-US.tar.xz': invalid or corrupted package
```

I had removed `/var/lib/pacman/db.lck` cause, an error was saying that.

> error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
> error: could not lock database: File exists
> if you're sure a package manager is not already
> running, you can remove /var/lib/pacman/db.lck

How to solve it?

Comment: Why not just download the tarball and signatures from torproject.org

Comment: @johndoe I had downloaded [the file](https://www.torproject.org/download/). In that tutorial he didn't do anything with that (without extracting it). I had downloaded it but, I couldn't understand what to do with it.

Comment: just extract the .tar.xz file, then inside the folder after extraction there is a file "Tor Browser Setup" or something similar, you just run that setup file and then it will configure tor browser automatically. After you run that setup file, after that then every time you enter that folder it changes and will be simply "Tor Browser". Running that "Tor Browser" file will start the browser.

Comment: @johndoe No! you are wrong. It's Linux not Windows. Linux software doesn't have installation format as Windows has. But, there's an shell file... I could open Tor Browser by executing that file. And, Manjaro (Arch-Based Linux) don't have debian(`deb` which is similarly like `exe`) formatted file also.

Comment: I could use "Tor Browser" But, I want answer of the question.

Comment: You should research and download the file that is designed for linux from the torproject website before you make claims like that